# Message Box error

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I've got a little problem with C++ message box. I was creating OpenGL application and I've found some errors there.

```
// OpenGL knihovny
#pragma comment (lib,"opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib,"glu32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib,"glaux.lib")
#include <windows.h> // Hlavičkový soubor pro Windows
#include <gl\gl.h> // Hlavičkový soubor pro OpenGL32 knihovnu
#include <gl\glu.h> // Hlavičkový soubor pro Glu32 knihovnu
#include <glaux.h> // Hlavičkový soubor pro Glaux knihovnu
//Globální proměnné
HDC hDC = NULL; // Privátní GDI Device Context
HGLRC hRC = NULL; // Trvalý Rendering Context
HWND hWnd = NULL; // Obsahuje Handle našeho okna
HINSTANCE hInstance; // Obsahuje instanci aplikace
bool keys[256]; // Pole pro ukládání vstupu z klávesnice
bool active = TRUE; // Ponese informaci o tom, zda je okno aktivní
bool fullscreen = TRUE; // Ponese informaci o tom, zda je program ve fullscreenu

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM); // Deklarace procedury okna (funkční prototyp)
GLvoid ReSizeGLScene(GLsizei width, GLsizei height) // Změna velikosti a inicializace OpenGL okna 
{
    if (height == 0) // Zabezpečení proti dělení nulou
    {
        height = 1; // Nastaví výšku na jedna
    }
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height); // Resetuje aktuální nastavení
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION); // Zvolí projekční matici
    glLoadIdentity(); // Reset matice
    gluPerspective(45.0f, (GLfloat)width / (GLfloat)height, 0.1f, 100.0f); // Výpočet perspektivy

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW); // Zvolí matici Modelview
    glLoadIdentity(); // Reset matice
}
int InitGL(GLvoid) // Všechno nastavení OpenGL
{
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH); // Povolí jemné stínování (smooth shading)
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f); // Nastaví barvu pozadí na černou
    glClearDepth(1.0f); // Nastavení hloubkového bufferu
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST); // Povolí hloubkové testování
    glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL); // Typ hloubkového testování
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST); // Nejlepší perspektivní korekce
    return TRUE; // Inicializace proběhla v pořádku
}
int DrawGLScene(GLvoid)// Vykreslování
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Smaže obrazovku a hloubkový buffer
    glLoadIdentity(); // Reset matice

    // Sem můžete kreslit

    return TRUE; // Vykreslení proběhlo v pořádku
}
GLvoid KillGLWindow(GLvoid) // Zavírání okna
{
    if (fullscreen) // Jsme ve fullscreenu?
    {
        ChangeDisplaySettings(NULL, 0); // Přepnutí do systému
        ShowCursor(TRUE); // Nastaví zobrazení kurzoru
    }
    if (hRC)// Máme rendering kontext?
    {
        if (!wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL)) // Jsme schopni oddělit kontexty?
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, "Release Of DC And RC Failed.", "SHUTDOWN ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        }
        if (!wglDeleteContext(hRC)) // Jsme schopni smazat RC?
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, "Release Rendering Context Failed.", "SHUTDOWN ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        }
        hRC = NULL; // Nastaví hRC na NULL
    }
```

Code is not completed, but I've got problem with Message Boxes.

```
if (hRC)// Máme rendering kontext?
{
    if (!wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL)) // Jsme schopni oddělit kontexty?
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Release Of DC And RC Failed.", "SHUTDOWN ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }
    if (!wglDeleteContext(hRC)) // Jsme schopni smazat RC?
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Release Rendering Context Failed.", "SHUTDOWN ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
    }
    hRC = NULL; // Nastaví hRC na NULL
}
```

I've got problems with message boxes. "Release Rendering Context Failed.", "Release Of DC And RC Failed.", "SHUTDOWN ERROR", "SHUTDOWN ERROR" - argument of type "const char*" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"
Thanks a lot for responses.
Aulipe

Answer (score 2):

Add `L` prefix before the string literals.

```
    MessageBox(NULL, L"Release Of DC And RC Failed.", L"SHUTDOWN ERROR", MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're compiling in Unicode mode (which is probably a good idea). That means Windows API functions will expect wide strings of `wchar_t` (in Unicode UTF-16 form) rather than ANSI strings of `char`.

You can create a wide string literal by prefixing with L - e.g. `L"Hello world"`.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
MessageBox(NULL, (LPTSTR)"TEXT" , (LPTSTR)"TEXT", MB_OK);
```

Comment: You can't convert an ANSI string to Unicode by casting. It'll compile, but it won't work.